# Javascript regular expression check flag support

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how can i check if a certain flag in regular expression is supported or not ? 
For some new flags, i keep getting "invalid regular expression flag" error.

Comment: `For some new flags,` could you list out those?

Comment: All available flags in JS and their usage is listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags

Comment: i mean how can i check them in code ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj There is also `y`, which is new-ish and not well supported.

Comment: @AvinashRaj and s as well.

Comment: @Michael js won't support s.

Comment: @AvinashRaj see [here](http://xregexp.com/flags/)

Comment: @Michael XRegExp is a third party library..

Comment: @AvinashRaj A this point, the "s" (aka single-line / dotall mode) an ECMAScript standard. There is a years-old bug in Firefox for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegExp constructor. It prevents syntax error and allows you to optionally detect and use that flag without aborting execution.

```
function isRegExpFlagSupported() {
    try {
        var regexp = new RegExp("foo.*bar", "s");
        return true;
    } catch (ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you execute it outside try-catch block like this,

```
var regexp = new RegExp("foo.*bar", "s");
```

it will throw error "invalid regular expression flag s".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the composition of the regex then can convert it into a string and use a regex to capture the letters after the last `/` character. Like `/test/gi.toString().match(/\w*$/); // <- ["gi"]`